# Why is this async call in componentDidMount affecting the time the component takes to mount?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous

I have a main menu screen, and a button that leads to the game screen (using `react-navigation`). Pressing that button should immediately navigate to the game screen. The game takes a bit of time to set up, so I want to show a loading icon until the game is ready. In my `GameComponent` class, I have the following for the constructor and `componentDidMount`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.tileRowRef = React.createRef<LetterTileRow>();
    this.inputRef = React.createRef<Input>();

    this.currentTypedWord = '';

    this.state = {
        errorMessage: '',
        gameLoading: true,
    }

    this.game = null;
}

componentDidMount(): void {
    this.game = WordGame.getSingleplayerGameInstance();
    this.game.setUpGame().then(() => this.gameFinishedLoading());
}
```

`setUpGame` is an async instance function in the `WordGame` class, which handles all game logic:

```
async setUpGame() {
    this.currentGameState.currentWord = await WordGame.generateStartWord();
    this.gameIsReady = true;
}
```

So in theory, the component should mount with the initial state being that the game is loading. It should call the async function that sets up the game, and when that completes, it should hide the loading icon and display the game. However, that is not what happens.

There is a strangely long pause after you press the button to navigate to the game. By the time the app navigates to the game screen, the game has already been loaded. To verify that it wasn't actually waiting for the game to finish loading, I added an artificial wait of 2 seconds to the `setUpGame` function, and in that case I was able to see a loading icon.

But I am really confused as to where this pause is coming from. I took screen recordings of the behavior with and without the line `this.game.setUpGame().then(() => this.gameFinishedLoading());` in `componentDidMount`. I overlayed them with the button press at the same instant and the difference is very clear: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IX_GyXENvmCJzvG0_TIU4deS8t6UGpjO

Comment: Did ever consider to create a loading page and call your async api’s  syncronously? Since your game could not work without the results of that apis I believe it is justified to run them syncronously.

Comment: It looks to me that gameIsReady should belong to the state, since you want a re-render to happen. Changing a simple class attribute won't trigger a re-render. Also consider using hooks for readaility (but this is purely oppinionated).

Comment: @EnriqueDev `gameIsReady` is a property of the game logic class, not the component which displays it. I included that so that if I want to come back to an existing game, I will be able to tell if it has already been set up.